# Facebook: What's wrong with this FQL statement?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get some data about myself (logged in) through the facebook.php API.

**This works:**

`SELECT name FROM user WHERE sex='female' AND uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1= me() )`

**This doesn't work:** *[gives "Exception: 1: An unknown error occurred"]*

`SELECT eid, name, location, start_time, pic_big, host, description 
FROM event 
WHERE eid IN (
    SELECT eid 
    FROM event_member 
    WHERE uid = me()
)`

I have the following permissions setup:

[image: App granted Perms]

Comment: what's the error you are getting ?

Comment: @ misterjinx - Facebook is kindly being specific with `"Exception: 1: An unknown error occurred"`

Comment: ohh...so `Exception 1` is causing this :) ok.

Comment: Does the subquery work on its own?

Comment: nope, what's weird is it used to work fine! I was hoping maybe someone else has also had problems (and found solutions)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is working just fine for me, most likely it's a permission issue. You see the small "*See more*" link under `Access my Profile information`?

Click it, if you can't see `Events` in the list then you need the [`user_events`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) permission.

**EDIT:**
Please go to [`fql.query`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/), in the Test Console paste the query and choose the application that causing the problem...if you got the expected result, then it's something to do with your code (the way you are calling the query, whether it's a PHP or other language).

If you are still facing the problem, try granting the `create_event` permission just to test.

Comment: @ifaour - yep events is in there, but i re-requested and approved the events and friends events permission anyway. Basically i've given the app pretty much every permission for my details!

Comment: @ifaour - Thanks for helping. No joy in test console either.. Tried adding the `user_events` permission, and have updated the screenshot in the OP to show all the permissions.... Could there be a problem with my app setup maybe?

Comment: @Haroldo: Okay, can you post your code that is actually calling this fql? maybe using [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @ifaour - The fact that it doesn't work in the test console makes me think there is a problem either either the App setup or the user permissions not the code?

Comment: @Haroldo: hmmm, I have a feeling that since you have the `offline_access` permission you can't use `me()` and instead use the user_id AND *maybe* appending the `access_token`

Comment: @ifaour - Thanks again for your time helping me with this. Ok i've gone for a blank canvas... I've `deleted the old app`, `created a new app` and `added the user_events, friends_events & create event permissions`. If i try the new app in the test console my queries are just 'loading' forever. Its gotta be something to do with a missing permission or a missing attribute when i create the app in facebook?

Comment: @Haroldo: maybe is has something to do with YOUR Facebook account and privacy, how about letting another user authorize your application and trying to query it..I would help you with this if you want.

Comment: @ifaour - Wow that would be really kind of you. I'll add my email to the question so you can add me as a friend on fb and I'll make you a co-developer. Let me know when you've added me and I'll edit the OP and delete my email! Thanks again, really appreciated

Comment: @Haroldo: lol, couldn't find you man..this is my [profile](http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=579187142) add me

Comment: @Haroldo: added, btw go to the [facebook](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211/facebook) chat room to continue the discussion there

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the facebook api but I'd start by removing all superfluous stuff

does this work ?

```
SELECT `eid` FROM `event` 
WHERE `eid` IN 
( SELECT `eid` FROM `event_member` WHERE `uid` = me() )
```

or even just

```
SELECT `eid` FROM `event_member` WHERE `uid` = me()
```

if it does add more stuff to it and don't forget the backticks.

To find out the correct fields you could use...

```
explain  `event`
```

This gives a list of fields and types assuming facebook uses mySQL

DC

Hmm ignore the comments about backticks and explain they arent used in FQL
so just try simplifying the query until the error occurs then you know what's triggering it.

DC

Comment: @Chris - Afraid I've already tried this. None of these work. Interestingly this code was working perfectly 2 weeks ago, and no mention of an API change anywhere in facebookland

Comment: I think this is why haroldo put the 'This works:' and 'This doesn't work:' code

Comment: But they are different tables, 'this works' FQL uses two entirely different tables. Its still a legitimate course of action and certainly doesn't warrant downvotes.

Comment: I have also some kind of related problem where my working code just stopped working without any error 3 days before. I dont know why facebook having such kind of problem. Their forums are also such issues in greater number